# Load html page inside ckeditor

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Is there any way to load a local html page to ckeditor?

```
<div class="text-area">
    <textarea cols="120" rows="10" id="editor" name="text"></textarea>
</div>
```

This is the script:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

    CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
        fullPage: true,
        allowedContent: true     

    });

    CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].setData('test.html');

</script>
}
```

Comment: Could you kindly let me know, if solution provided worked well, please?

Comment: Yes sure sir. It worked, but I changed the editor for several reason. Thank you for the help anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load this page with smth and only then fill CKEditor with data you got.

**Note**, that .setData() is async function, so don't do any data modification right after, until you will got confirmation that data in editor has been properly changed.

**Javascript:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'test.html', true);

xhr.onload = function() {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].setData(this.response);
  } else {
    // process error status here
  }
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
    // process error status here
};

xhr.send();
```

**Javascript + jQuery**

```
$.get('test.html')
  .done(response=>{CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].setData(response);})
  .fail(/** process error here **/);
```

**Javascript + fetch**

Not all browsers are supporting this one.

Polyfill is here: https://github.com/github/fetch

Support table is here: https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch

```
fetch('test.html')
  .then(response=>{CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].setData(response.text);})
  .catch(/** process error here **/);
```

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it using your answer with just 'Javascript'. However when CKEditor loads the html page, the text formatting is gone.
What should I do to retain the formatting?